# handle PushKit payload without loading storyboard or other interactive features

Tags: ios, launch, pushkit

We have an app that uses PushKit to receive notifications. (It is not a VoIP app but we have a dispensation from Apple to use PushKit due to being a special app category that has specific needs in healthcare).

When the app is not running and a PushKit notification comes in, the system launches the app into the background and the push kit delegate payload processor is called (PKPushRegistryDelegate pushRegistry:didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:forType:).  Then the app is closed down again.  The app never reaches a graphical interactive state.

This is fine and how it should be.  However, iOS does a complete app launch, loading the storyboard and everything.  In addition, in the UIApplicationDelegate application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, launch options is nil, so you don't know you're being launched to handle push kit and won't be going interactive.

This is causing us problems as our app does a complete, "heavy" set up of resources, server connections, etc. that don't need and shouldn't be set up to just handle the PushKit notification.  This is causing us some issues as certain things being connected (server connections etc.) cause some behavior we don't want when the PushKit is being processed (and then the app going away).

Is there a way to be able know you were launched for pushkit purposes and not do all the app setup that normally happens?  (If the app were to then transition to Active we should be able to use the normal active state transition to finish setup)

Answer (score 0):

Once you getting Pushkit payload in didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload, you have to schedule local notification with info based on pushkit payload. then you can make your app interactive. you can also keep details in NSUserDefault and check on local notification tap events and in didFinishLaunchingWithOption.

This way you can initiate storyboard and get redirect to particular viewControllers.

Let me know if you need more clarification on same.

Comment: Yes, we are sending our own local notification etc.  However, when iOS launches the app in the background to process the -didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload, it also loads the Storyboard etc. at that point, which is what we are trying to avoid as it does not need to be loaded just to process the pushkit payload.  We worked around it by setting the storyboard in the plist to nothing and then loading it ourselves when we detect we have gone interactive.

Comment: Is your problem resolved? You can keep sound file in local notification, app will be active in background till sound file plays. Also you can keep flag in NSUserDefault and check on disfinishlaunchingwithoption and change rootviewcontroller to reach directly to your particular viewcontroller. Then through some feature you can again set back to original rootviewcontroller process.

Comment: It is "resolved" by setting the storyboard to nil in the plist and loading it later by hand.   It would be nice to have an Apple supplied and supported method for this.  But what we do works fine.

Comment: Great, have a happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for keeping up with this.